# I keep getting the bad address exception, any knows why?

Tags: mips

I'm trying to do a simple program that counts the number of characters in a string . It seems I follow the structure but I keep getting the same bad address error, anyone knows why?

```
    .data
array:  .space 100
prompt1: .asciiz " Enter the string that you would like to reverse and calculate character: "
prompt2: .asciiz " "

    .text
main:
    la  $a1, array  # allocate the array space      
ask:        
    li  $v0, 4      # print String
    la  $a0, prompt1    # load prompt1
    syscall
    li  $v0, 8      # read the string
    syscall
    move    $a1, $v0    # move input to $a1
    li  $t0 ,0      # $t0 will hold the actual numbers of character in the string        
loopCount:        
    lbu $t1, 0($a1)     # load the next character into t1
    beqz    $t1, print  # check for the null character
    addi    $a1, $a1, 1     # increment the string pointer
    addi    $t0, $t0, 1     # increment the count
    b   loopCount   # return to the top of the loop
print:    
    li  $v0, 1
    move    $a0, $t0
    syscall
```

Answer (score 1):

You should load the address of your buffer in `$a0` and the size of the buffer in `$a1` before the syscall to read the string.